# Button on top of TabView (carousel page style) — gesture issue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture

I have a ZStack, containing a TabView (page carousel style) with images. On top of that, there is a button. The button is not working (neither of the print statements below output). I think this is due to the gesture of the tab view overriding the button tap.

I've tried `simultaneousGesture` after some searching, and also tried `zIndex`, but these don't have any effect. How can I allow for button taps, while also allowing the gesture swipe for the TabView?

```swift
ZStack {
    TabView(selection: $selectedPhoto) {
        //images
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    VStack {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Button {
                print("clicked")
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    .font(.system(.title3))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.init(hex: "FFFFFF").opacity(0.2))
                            .frame(width: 64)
                    )
            }
            .frame(width: 64)
            .zIndex(100)
            .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                print("also clicked")
            })
            Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
}
.frame(height: 300)
```